# how to add value to textarea

Tags: php, ajax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add default value for html <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007219/how-to-add-default-value-for-html-textarea)

I am using ajax to send data from the form to the database and I have probem:

```
<input class="input" type="text" name="do_kogo" id="odbiorca" size="25" value="<?php print $odbiorca; ?>" />
<input class="input" id="temat" type="text" name="temat" size="25" value="<?php print $temat; ?>"/>
<textarea id="tresc_area" name="tresc" cols="45" rows="10" ></textarea>
```

As you can see I am changing the values to php equivalent and I don't know how can I change the value of the textarea to put there `<?php print $tresc; ?>`Please help me if somebody know how to do this. I would be so grateful.

Answer (score 4):

You can add value in between `<textarea>` starting and ending tag.

```
<textarea id="tresc_area" name="tresc" cols="45" rows="10" ><?php print $tresc; ?></textarea>
```

Comment: ahh I thought about that and tried it. I realise my problem wasn't here. Thanks for the answer @Dr. Dan