# Double Quotes and $_POST

Tags: php, html, post

Hello I am using $_POST['value']; to grab value on the 2nd page and all the combination works including ' but when I use ", it doesnt work, so let say I will write "test" and on the 2nd page will get empty $_POST[value]; I have magic Quotes OFF and this is only happening on input fields but not on the textarea fields. I am not escaping any strings using mysql-real-escape-string Very strange, please help.

```
<form method="post" name="UploadForm" id="UploadForm" action="sellitem2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

<input class="button_date" type="text" name="auction_title" style="text-transform:none;" id="auction_title" value="<?php echo $_POST['auction_title']; ?>" size="32" minlength="2" maxlength="21" required/>

<input class="button2" style="border-right:none; font-size:13px;" name="Next Step" id="submit" type="submit" value="Next Step" onClick="removeFocus()"/>

</form>
```

And on the second page I have got nothing once typed "TEST" or any " inside that field

Comment: i am not clear on where you are using "test". can u post your code and add the variation in as a comment

Comment: I am inserting to input field value "TEST" with quotes and I am not receiving that on the other page once inserted just TEST everything is okay

Comment: u mean $_POST['auction_title']=""Test""?

Answer (score 0):

Instead  of `"test"` use `\"test\"`

Or Even better use:

```php
$input_arr = array();   

//grabs the $_POST variables and adds slashes    
foreach ($_POST as $key => $input_arr) {   
  $_POST[$key] = addslashes($input_arr);   
}
```

Comment: Why are you down-voting?

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn HTML. And especially tag attributes syntax. In PHP you have to use `htmlspecialchars` to encode them.

Answer (score 0):

You can write the content of a textarea directly into it, iirc there's no value attribute:

```
  <textarea><?php echo $foo;?></textarea>
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6007262/838733

And you shouldn't write `$_POST` values directly without encoding them to prevent XSS attacks.