# Making a text area with default text

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I wonder could anyone help with this.
I'm making a Java compiler app through phonegap and I have a textarea in which I would just like to have the Java Class name already default in the text box(and it not disappear)

So I have as follows

```
    <div>
            <label for="source">Source Code:</label>
            <textarea cols="35" rows="10" name="source" id="source" value="class TryMe{"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="input">Input: <span class="description">(Data that will be given to the program on the stdin.)</span></label>
            <textarea cols="35" rows="3" name="input" id="input"></textarea>
        </div>

        <div>
```

and just to highlight  what I mean I've added "value= "class TryMe{" just so you know what I mean.
Is it easiest to just make a javascript function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add default value for html <textarea>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007219/how-to-add-default-value-for-html-textarea)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a default value for an html `<textarea>` is like this

```
<textarea cols="35" rows="10" name="source" id="source">  VALUE HERE  </textarea>
```

Comment: Great thanks, Did it and while it works, the text appears in the centre of the textbox, any idea why?

Comment: You need to keep it all on one line, any whitespace within your textarea value will be rendered too. That includes new lines

Comment: Drag over the contents of your textarea input, does it have lots of whitespace ?

Comment: yeah I just used &#13;&#10; in the end, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Textareas do not have a value attribute. You simple add the text within the element

```
<textarea>class TryMe{</textarea>
```

You can also use placeholders

```
<textarea placeholder="class TryMe{"></textarea>
```