# How to add default value for html <textarea> from json passed from server in Pug?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

Not a duplicate of [How to add default value for html <textarea>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007219/how-to-add-default-value-for-html-textarea) but very similar, I just want to do that in Pug.

I want to set a default value for my html `<textarea>` that is populated from data passed by to me by my router in Node.js.

I've tried
`textarea {JSON.parse(fromServer.myJson).author}`
`textarea {{JSON.parse(fromServer.myJson).author}}`
`textarea JSON.parse(fromServer.myJson).author`

All I get are text areas populated with my code instead of the values that I'm passing in that code.

`fromServer.myJson` is a really hacked together piece of data, it's a String that was json inside the json object `fromServer` that's being passed from MySQL. I face the same problem if I use `fromSever.title` which is a more sane object.

Comment: `textarea #{JSON.parse(fromServer.myJson).author}`