# Form text area value going hidden after refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

I am working on some form when i refresh the page the value which is present there is going blank if i do a right click and doing an inspect element the value is present there which is like this.

```
<textarea class="inputbox" tabindex="23" rows="5" name="keySkills" id="keySkills" style="width: 400px;" value="Configuration  of  controlling  area  (CO),  Maintaining  CO   version   and
Maintaining number ranges for planning and actual  transactions  in  CO  and
Defining primary and secondary Cost Element"></textarea>
```

But in console of google if i am running this code which is returning blank.

```
var value = document.getElementById('keySkills');
console.log(variable.value)
```

It is showing me undefined. but if i do

```
console.log(variable)
```

It is prinitng this

```
<textarea class="inputbox" tabindex="23" rows="5" name="keySkills" id="keySkills" style="width: 400px;" value="Configuration  of  controlling  area  (CO),  Maintaining  CO   version   and
Maintaining number ranges for planning and actual  transactions  in  CO  and
Defining primary and secondary Cost Element"></textarea>
```

Any idea how to fix this i want the value to remin in the text area itself

Comment: Are you doing anything to save this value after refresh?

Comment: Don't use textarea `value="text"`.  Instead, put the text between the 2 tags : `<textarea>Your text goes here</textarea>`

Comment: Check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007219/how-to-add-default-value-for-html-textarea). Basically what Archer said.

Comment: @Archer Yeah it is fixed the way you have said But the problem is that in backend php code will use this value in order to save it in back end

Comment: You can put in both ;)

Comment: @Adriano Yeah true but is there any fix in at this way? without digging lot into backend code? I just want to show the field after refresh as well using plain javascript

Comment: Well, if you want to do it in javascript-only, you can try something like this: get the value of `value` and place it as text object.   
  
`variable.innerHTML = variable.getAttribute("value");`

Comment: Glad it helped - I've added the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to post the content of a textarea element to your backend you shouldn't rely on the `value` attribute.  That's fine for many other elements, but a textarea contains the value between the opening and closing tags, like this...

```
<textarea>This is your text value</text>
```

That text will be available in whatever server application is handling your form submission.